# I want me bot to send a message everytime it errors

Tags: discord.js

I wanted to make it so everytime my bot had an error it would send the error in a channel but it does nothing

```
bot.on('error', function (err) {
  bot.guilds.get("609118791854456860").channels.get("609118791854456865").send(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the [Error Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-error) is called
`whenever the client's WebSocket encounters a connection error.`
I believe the key is **connection error**. So if this event is called, you are no longer connected or something is wrong with the connection. Therefore no message can be sent if it can't connect.

One workaround is what Cloud has in his answer, and use the
 `process.on("uncaughtException", e => {})`

But just in case the error is fatal and the bot can't connect. You should *save* the error to a .txt file so whenever the bot **successfully** re-connects, you send whatever is in that file to your desired channel. Then have the bot delete the file if it successfully sent the message.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Client emits an event called "error". This code here should catch all uncaught errors and send them in a channel of your choosing:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", e => {
    console.error(e);
    Client.channels.get("YOUR CHANNEL ID").send(e.stack.slice(0, 2000); //ensure the stack trace is not too long, messages are limited to 2000 characters
    process.exit();
});
```

In this code snippet, I've named my `new Discord.Client()` instance `Client`, it seems you've named yours `bot`, so you can swap the two names.

Comment: The `unhandledRejection` event may also be useful to you!